# Can't get fastled.h and remoteme.h to work together

Tags: wifi, nodemcu, led-strip

I'm trying to make a Google Assistant controlled LED strip, but I'm stuck. I can control the on board LED of the nodemcu with Google Assistant, and I can control a LED strip too, but I can't combine the two. This is my code:

```cpp
#define WIFI_NAME "****************"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "********"
#define DEVICE_ID 1
#define DEVICE_NAME "Google_ESP"
#define TOKEN "************"

#define FASTLED_ESP8266_NODEMCU_PIN_ORDER
#include "FastLED.h"

#include <RemoteMe.h>
#include <RemoteMeSocketConnector.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#define ledpin D0

RemoteMe& remoteMe = RemoteMe::getInstance(TOKEN, DEVICE_ID);

//*************** CODE FOR CONFORTABLE VARIABLE SET *********************

inline void setLedstrip(boolean b) {remoteMe.getVariables()->setBoolean("Ledstrip", b); }

//*************** IMPLEMENT FUNCTIONS BELOW *********************


// How many leds in your strip?
#define NUM_LEDS 120

// For led chips like Neopixels, which have a data line, ground, and power, you just
// need to define DATA_PIN.  For led chipsets that are SPI based (four wires - data, clock,
// ground, and power), like the LPD8806 define both DATA_PIN and CLOCK_PIN
#define DATA_PIN D3

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

boolean ledsOn = 0;

void onLedstripChange(boolean b) {
    Serial.printf("onLedstripChange: b: %d\n",b);

    if(ledsOn != b){
        if(b == 1){
            turnLedsOn();
        }
        else{
            turnLedsOff();
        }

        ledsOn = b;
    }
}


void setup() {
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

    Serial.begin(9600);

    WiFi.begin(WIFI_NAME, WIFI_PASSWORD);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(100);
    }

    remoteMe.getVariables()->observeBoolean("Ledstrip" ,onLedstripChange);

    remoteMe.setConnector(new RemoteMeSocketConnector());
    remoteMe.sendRegisterDeviceMessage(DEVICE_NAME);

    pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
}


void loop() {
  remoteMe.loop();
}


void turnLedsOn(){
  digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
  leds[0] = CHSV(0, 100, 100);
  FastLED.show();
}

void turnLedsOff(){
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  leds[0] = CHSV(0, 0, 0);
  FastLED.show();
}
```

As you can see, it should turn on the on board LED and the first LED of the strip. It only does the on board one.

Comment: Hi @CodeHard, Could you provide links or the actual code to the two programs that work? Handy if you could provide links to the libraries you used. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, okay. Nevermind...

I just read my code of the ledstrip only program and the google assistant ledstrip to look for differences, and found out it didn't work because I used pin D3 instead of pin 3...

Comment: Also, `ledpin` should be `0` instead of `D0`.

Comment: Please add that as an answer down below. You can answer your own question and get some upvotes from solving it (hopefully).